# Overlapping controls - Canvas.ZIndex not working

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7.1

Background:

For my Windows Phone application, I have created a UserControl called CharacterPresenter (let's call it CP, for short). This is a small rectangle with a Border control which I can toggle between PhoneAccentBrush and Transparent so the user can see when it is selected.

I have created a second UserControl called MultiCharacterPresenter (MCP). This contains a horizontally-oriented StackPanel to display multiple CP controls on a single line. This too has a Border control so the user can see when the whole line is selected.

Note that only one *Presenter can be selected at any time and all BorderThickness="6".

Requirement:

I can't have a 12px. gap (caused by the Transparent Borders) between each CP so I set the Border Margin="-6,-6,-6,-6". This puts the Border outside the rectangle bounding the CP UserControl and allows the CP controls to form one continuous line inside the MCP.

So then, when a CP is selected, the Border overlaps the neighbouring CP controls. That's fine since the selected CP has the user's focus so it's OK that other CP controls may be partially obscured.

Problem:

The issue is that the right-side of the Border of each CP is **underneath** the next CP on the right. Only the right-most CP shows a complete border. I want the whole Border to show when a CP is selected but it is partially hidden.

Non-solution:

I tried setting the Canvas.ZIndex of all the Border controls to 1 (while the default for all other content is zero) which should put the Border controls on top of everything else... but that didn't work. I'm not sure why.

If it makes a difference, I'm adding the CP controls one-by-one to the MCP in code, based on the data. So perhaps the ZIndex only works when all the controls are rendered at the same time, e.g. if they are already present in the XAML (not added programmatically).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The layout of controls contained in any `Panel` relative to each other is defined by the `Panel` itself. In your case you're using a `StackPanel`, which has no concept of Z-index. It lays out items in the order that they are added to its `Children` collection. The `ZIndex` attached property you're using is defined on `Canvas` because it is used by the `Canvas` panel as part of its layout process.

Why don't you try changing the BorderThickness to 0 instead?

Comment: OK, so the Canvas.ZIndex is a non-starter. No such thing as an implicit canvas then. Not sure how the zero-width border solves anything? The CP on the right will still be on top of it. Unless you are suggesting to allow the border to push (i.e. move laterally) the CP on the right, to the right, by the thickness of the border? That's not a visual effect I would want. Did I understand you correctly?